# javascript function that needs to get div id from img onclick

Tags: image, html, onclick

I have a javascript function that I need to give her an 'ID' of div from onClick img tag
Is there any one that can help me I don't know what to do:

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: Give us a demo in jsfiddle.net means more than your only one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

**Html:**

```
<img onclick="imgClicked"></img>

<div id="foo">...</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
    window.imgClicked = function(){
         var div = document.getElementById("foo");
         ...//do anything you want...
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the div , on which the image is clicked by using `event.target.nodeName`

Setup an click event handler for Image, then u can use above to find out the div of the image clicked.hope it helps..